# exact/inexact results like sqrt and integer roots

Tags: scheme, r6rs, inexact-arithmetic

[R6RS 3.4 Implementation requirements](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-6.html) reads

> ... Potentially inexact operations such as `sqrt`, when applied to exact
>   arguments, should produce exact answers whenever possible (for example
>   the square root of an exact 4 ought to be an exact 2).

(1) Does this mean that `(* 0 2.2)` must produce `0.0` but never `0` as result?

> However, this
>   is not required. ...

(2) Does this mean that `(/ 4 2)` may also produce 2.0 as result?

(3) And are there implementations that provide integer roots in this manner? How do I get the functionality of integer square roots in general? (Here is the [index](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs-lib/r6rs-lib-Z-H-21.html)) (Please no recursive/iterative implementation)

Comment: In Racket, `(exact? (sqrt 4))`, `(exact? (* 0 2.2))` and `(exact? (/ 4 2))` produce `#t`. So does `(exact? (/ 4 3))` since `1 1/3` is an exact number.

Comment: @LePetitPrince: With freshly installed Racket v6.1.1, `(* (/ 0.0 0.0) 0)` and `(* 0 (/ 1 0.0))` and `(/ 0 0.0)` all produce `0` (thus exact). Is this OK?

Comment: I would have expected `(/ 0.0 0.0)` to throw an exception but it yields `+nan.0` because `(inexact? 0.0)` is `#t`. The rest is explained [here](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/numbers.html).

Comment: FWIW, Guile yields different results for some expressions: `(exact? (* 0 2.2))` is `#f`, `(* (/ 0.0 0.0) 0)`, `(* 0 (/ 1 0.0))` and `(/ 0 0.0)` are `+nan.0`, which seems more logical to me.

Comment: @LePetitPrince `(/ 0 0.0)` _should_ be NaN. But _multiplying_ anything by an exact zero is, mathematically speaking, an exact zero, so Scheme implementations are allowed (but not required) to account for that.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Multiplying a number by exact 0 is 0. Multiplying a NaN by 0 should remain NaN, because the NaN does not magically become a number.

Comment: @LePetitPrince True, I think I can agree with that, in the sense that NaN means "I don't know what this number is", and that number could potentially be infinity. But certainly, any non-infinite number multiplied by exact 0 is 0.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young: That's what I try to understand. If you have a float value, that value is by definition inexact. It may come from some inexact computation. Actually, maybe it really should be NaN, but due to roundoffs, the division `(/ zero zero)` did not yield that result.

Answer (score 2):

R6RS has `exact-integer-sqrt`. It returns two values, the square root and the remainder. You can discard the second value if you want.

Implementations are allowed (but not required) to consider `(* 0 x)` (multiplying anything by an exact zero) to be exact zero for any x. See the [R6RS description](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-14.html#node_idx_496) of the `*` procedure.